# Need help in training Tesseract with application images

Tags: tesseract

We are using tesseract to perform actions and verifications for our application. But we are facing issues for some of the characters. As i have never tried training if any one can help with this.

Any link for how to train with application image.
how to prepare training data.
How to do the training in windows if possible.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The [tesseract-ocr/tesstrain](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesstrain) could train some of the characters according the images and their ground truth.

But if you want to run it on windows, you need the following tools:

1. setup Cygwin on your computer and make sure that the weget/bc/make packages have been installed.
2. setup python3
3. tesseract4.0+ and its training tools

Then you need change some places in the makefile in tesseract-ocr/tesstrain:

1. change TESSDATA to the .traineddata in your computer.
2. change the Path of the WORDLIST_FILE/NUMBERS_FILE/PUNC_FILE:

```
       WORDLIST_FILE = data/$(MODEL_NAME).wordlist
       NUMBERS_FILE := data/$(MODEL_NAME).numbers
       PUNC_FILE := data/$(MODEL_NAME).punc
```

3. Download the .wordlist/.numbers/.punc files from the [langdata_lstm](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/langdata_lstm). e.g，if your language is english, you should download them from langdata_lstm/eng. Rename them as $(MODEL_NAME).wordlist/$(MODEL_NAME).numbers/$(MODEL_NAME).punc
4. find the code:

```
    $(ALL_GT): $(shell find $(GROUND_TRUTH_DIR) -name '*.gt.txt')
```

and change it to :

```
    $(ALL_GT): $(wildcard $(GROUND_TRUTH_DIR)/*.gt.txt)
```

5. find the code:

```
    $(ALL_LSTMF): $(patsubst %.gt.txt,%.lstmf,$(shell find $(GROUND_TRUTH_DIR) -name '*.gt.txt'))
        @mkdir -p $(OUTPUT_DIR)
        find $(GROUND_TRUTH_DIR) -name '*.lstmf' | python3 shuffle.py $(RANDOM_SEED) > "$@"
```

and change it to :

```
    $(ALL_LSTMF): $(patsubst %.gt.txt,%.lstmf,$(wildcard $(GROUND_TRUTH_DIR)/*.gt.txt))
        @mkdir -p $(OUTPUT_DIR)
        find $(GROUND_TRUTH_DIR) -name '*.lstmf' -exec echo {} \; | sort -R -o "$@"
```

6. Change all the python3 to python.

Then you could do as the instructions on [tesseract-ocr/tesstrain](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesstrain). Search tesstrain windows in Github for help.